# The fieldset’s background color gets out of border in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The fieldset’s background color gets out of border in IE. I have a table with background color set to blue and the fieldset’s background color set to white. How can I fix this in IE?

My CSS :

```
fieldset {margin:10px;}         
fieldset legend {font-size: 14px; font-style:normal;}
```

I am creating fieldset dynamically.

```
newFieldset = document.createElement('fieldset');
newLegend = document.createElement('legend');
newLegend.innerHTML = 'Claimant Information';
newFieldset.appendChild(newLegend);
OverdueReportsSummaryDetailsTableDiv.appendChild(newFieldset);
```

Please see attachment (click to enlarge)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You forgot to provide your HTML.

Comment: one step better, post up a screenshot so we can more easily see the issue

Comment: Your JavaScript is irrelevant to your problem. You need to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo with your HTML/CSS, showing the problem you described: `"The fieldset’s background color gets out of border in IE"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well-known IE bug, and occurs regardless of whether you use JavaScript to generate the elements or write the HTML yourself.

`legend` is a child of `fieldset`, but since it's located slightly "above" the top edge of the `fieldset`, IE (incorrectly) extends the background color of the `fieldset` to contain the `legend`.

An easy workaround is to absolutely position the `legend` to take it out of normal element flow, and manually adjust its location so it rests roughly where it normally is. Also position the `fieldset` relatively so the `legend` remains in its vicinity.

Something like this (adjust the values as needed):

```
fieldset {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}

fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5em;
    left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
}
```