# Background appearing outside of the Fieldset's border in IE8

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I have been working on doing CSS hacks to make things work in Internet explorer 7 and 8 that normally work in Chrome/Firefox. I have fixed most of the issues but I can't figure this one out and I was hoping for some help.

Here is how my login box looks normally:

[image]

And here is how it looks in IE 8:

[image]

Id like to get them looking the same, but at a minimum fix how the color goes past the border. Any thoughts?

Edit:

here is the html/server control that renders the login box:

```html
<form>
<fieldset style="width: 20" align="center" id="login_border">
    <legend id="login_box">Login</legend>
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" 
        TitleText="">
    </asp:Login>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
#login_border 
{
    Border: 0.25em black solid; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    background-color: #fdbe12;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -142px;
}

#login_box 
{
    Border: 0.1em black solid; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
    padding: 0.2em 0.8em;
    background-color: White;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.login 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Comment: my thought is, this has absolutely nothing to do with C#!

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fieldset’s background color gets out of border in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667259/the-fieldsets-background-color-gets-out-of-border-in-ie)

Comment: @David - have you looked at the [IE7.js project](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)? There are also IE8 and IE9 versions of the library, which may help with some of your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to give negative margin-top to legend and this will get fixed.

```
*margin-top:-22px;   //for IE7
margin-top:-22px\0/; //for IE8, Note `\0/` characters here.
```